# Use OpenCamera libraray to get captured media as result

Tags: android, camera

I am using OpenCamera library 
https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/
to capture images and videos in my application, i need to call the mainActivity for result and stop the activity and get the uri of the captured media directly after capturing is done.
i tried going through the code to get the uri and stop the activity but with no luck, i couldnt find any documentation to help me with my task.

Answer (score 0):

In StorageUtils. java in broadcastFile function i added my code to send the stored vedio url and finish the activity to send the result to the caller activity, also did the same for image captured in the savingImage function thread.
although the library has a capture_image intent and record_video intent to return result but it behaves like native camera apps where you cannot call the camera for both image and video at the same time, so i send by another intent for both images and videos by clicking one button giving the user the freedom to choose after launching the camera app.

Comment: can you share the example plzz